# Conditional Jolt spec for nested array

Tags: json, multidimensional-array, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I am trying to write Jolt spec for the following input. I need to populate the **primaryEmail** field based on the condition if **primary** field is true in the **emails** array

```json
[
  {
    "uid": "1234mark",
    "name": "mark",
    "userName": "markw",
    "displayName": "Mark W",
    "emails": [
      {
        "primary": false,
        "value": "mark@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "primary": true,
        "value": "mark@hotmail.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "uid": "9876steve",
    "name": "steve",
    "userName": "stevew",
    "displayName": "Steve W",
    "emails": [
      {
        "primary": false,
        "value": "steve@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "primary": true,
        "value": "steve@hotmail.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The desired output is

```json
[
  {
    "user": {
      "externalId": "1234mark",
      "name": "mark",
      "userName": "markw",
      "displayName": "Mark W",
      "primaryEmail": "mark@hotmail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "externalId": "9876steve",
      "name": "steve",
      "userName": "stevew",
      "displayName": "Steve W",
      "primaryEmail": "steve@hotmail.com"
    }
  }
]
```

But I get the following incorrect output since I am not able to populate the **primaryEmail** field conditionally properly.

```json
[
  {
    "user": {
      "externalId": "1234mark",
      "name": "mark",
      "userName": "markw",
      "displayName": "Mark W"
    }
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "externalId": "9876steve",
      "name": "steve",
      "userName": "stevew",
      "displayName": "Steve W"
    }
  }
]
```

The spec I have created is the following

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "uid": "[&1].user.externalId",
        "name": "[&1].user.name",
        "userName": "[&1].user.userName",
        "displayName": "[&1].user.displayName",
        "title": "[&1].user.title",
        "emails": {
          "*": {
            "primary": {
              "true": {
                "@(2,value)": "primaryEmail"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Could someone please help with this query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to go **5** levels the three up from the innermost object while adding an extra node called `user` such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "uid": "[&1].user.externalId",
        "*": "[&1].user.&", // the attributes except for "uid" and "emails" array
        "emails": {
          "*": {
            "primary": {
              "true": {
                "@(2,value)": "[&5].user.&2Email" // replicate literal "primary" by using &2
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton Barbaros for your quick help. I have marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: could you please tell me what is the difference between using direct value with ampersand versus it being enclosed in square brackets.. for example : &5 and [&5]

Comment: `&..` generates objects with labels based on the values at that level(such as 0,1,2.. if they are indexes similar to our case), while `[&..]` generates array-alike(square-bracketed) results such as array of objects like our current case, and no label will be generated unless they are prefixed like `SomeNode[&<int>]` @ayan_2587